# Why do the components of an equivalent kernel sum to 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

Let $\textbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. We define 
$$
X := 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & x_1 & \cdots & x_1^k \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  &  & \vdots  \\
  1 & x_n & \cdots & x_n^k
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (k+1)}
$$
and a function $b:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ with $b: x_0 \mapsto (1, x_0, \dots, x_0^k)^T$. Then, we can compute the equivalent kernel $$l(x_0) = b(x_0)^T(X^T X)^{-1} X^T$$ for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. The question is: how can we prove that the sum of the components of $l(x_0)$ is $1$ for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

---

Further notes:

This question arises in the context of local polynomial regression and it is a simplified version of Exercise 6.2 in "Elements of Statistical Learning".

I tried induction over $k$ and used a [formula for blockwise inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the components of $l(x_0)$ can be expressed as $l(x_0) \mathbf{1}_{n}$. After defining $S_k := \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k$ we can rewrite the sum as follows
\begin{align*}
l(x_0) \mathbf{1}_{n} 
  &= b(x_0)^T (X^TX)^{-1} X^T \mathbf{1}_{n} \\
  &= b(x_0)^T (X^TX)^{-1} (S_0, \dots, S_k)^T \\
  &= b(x_0)^T 
      \begin{pmatrix}
        S_0 & S_1 & \cdots & S_k \\
        \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
        S_k & S_{k+1} & \cdots & S_{2k}
      \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
      \begin{pmatrix}
        S_0 \\
        \vdots \\
        S_k
      \end{pmatrix} \\
  &\overset{(*)}{=} b(x_0)^T e_1 \\
  &= 1 \;.
\end{align*}
At step $(*)$ we used the definition of the inverse of a matrix, i.e. $A^{-1} A = I = (e_1, \dots, e_n)$ for all invertible matrices $A$.